# Returning value from goroutine with socketio

Tags: go, websocket, goroutine

I'm currently working on a desktop application that uses Electron and communicates to a Go binary for a majority of the backend computations via websocket.

I have, for example

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    socketio "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
)

func foo() bool {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
    return true
}
```

I will represent my websocket server using the `go-socket` module as

```golang
server.OnEvent("/", "test", func(s socketio.Conn, value string) bool {
    return foo()
}
```

My application is very large and deep so I have minimized the general concept for simplicity sake. I am looking to run `foo()` as a goroutine and returning the given value to my socket server.

What is the best way to do this?

**EDIT**

Now that I've thought more about it, I believe it will be better to not return the value from `foo()` but still start it as a goroutine and instead emit the response to a separate receiver on the front-end.

Comment: You should first check whether handlers are called in their own goroutine, they usually are.

Comment: Should the goroutine which runs `foo()` be started for every event?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but probably not a good approach:

```sh
server.OnEvent("/", "test", func(s socketio.Conn, value string) bool {
    c := make(chan bool)
    var x bool
    go func() {
        x = foo()
        c <- true
    }()
    <-c

    return x
}
```

I have used a channel to execute the goroutine first. After successfully execute the goroutine then the main routine will be executed.

Comment: This won't work, the function will exit before the goroutine is done.